# MySQL: COM_SELECT increases at a rate of 1000 / sec, but processlist is almost empty

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a strange situation on one of my MySQL servers.

`mysqladmin status` and `SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status` clearly shows, that MySQL experiences a load of about 1000 queries per second. `top` says, that MySQL server takes about 250% of CPU on that 8-core system.

But if I do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` I can see only about 4-5 entries there with very quick queries, taking less than a second to complete. If I run `mytop`, it shows qps of 2-3 and same queries, not more.

How can this be? What could be excluded from process list?

MySQL is 5.6 there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` command only shows you which *threads* (like tcp connections) are currently running and what they are doing. The fact that it only shows you 4-5 entries just means there are 4-5 concurrent connections.

These connections could very well be processing 200 small/simple queries per second, thus running queries that take 0.005 seconds to complete each.

If you want to be certain of what's happening, you could also temporarily enable the [General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html), so you can actually see all queries that are run by the server.

Comment: Not "4-5 concurrent connections"; rather "4-5 of the connections are actually involved with a query at the instant".  The "Sleep" connections are still connections, just that they are 'between' queries at that instant.

Answer (score 0):

There's "latency" and there's "throughput".  You have 1000 qps throughput.  And you could have a *few* times that before you saturate the CPU cores or something else.

Latency is how long it takes for the query to finish -- from the client's point of view.  If all the queries take 5ms to run, and you are issuing 1000/sec:

```
0.005 sec/query * 1000 queries/sec = 5 queries in progress at any moment
```

The numbers are reasonable.

I would turn on the slowlog with `long_query_time = 1` (second) and keep an eye on the slowlog -- it will eventually show you the "worst" queries, that is, the ones that should be looked into.